# DataGridComboBoxColumn: how to set TextBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I'm developing a WPF with C#, .NET Framework 4.5.1, MVVM Light framework and Entity Framework 6.1.3.

I have this `DataGrid` in a window:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LevelConfigurationDataGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0" ItemsSource="{Binding LevelConfigs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CODE_LEVEL}" Header="Nivel"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LEVEL_NAME}" Header="Nombre"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IS_ACTIVE}" Header="¿Activa?"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Tipo de código" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CODE_TYPE}" SelectedItemBinding="{x:Null}" TextBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Origen del código" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CODE_SOURCE}" SelectedItemBinding="{x:Null}" TextBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Tipo de Helper Code" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding HELPER_CODE_TYPE}" SelectedItemBinding="{x:Null}" TextBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Origen de Helper Code" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding HELPER_CODE_SOURCE}" SelectedItemBinding="{x:Null}" TextBinding="{x:Null}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding QUANTITY}" Header="Cantidad"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding REMAINING_CODES}" Header="Restantes"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TRZ_ENDPOINT}" Header="TRZ IP"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TRZ_ENDPORT}" Header="TRZ Puerto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And on `MainViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION> LevelConfigs
{
    get { return m_LevelConfigs; }
    set
    {
        m_LevelConfigs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("LevelConfigs");
    }
}
```

And on `CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION`:

```
public class CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION
{
    public byte CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }
    public string LEVEL_NAME { get; set; }
    public bool IS_ACTIVE { get; set; }
    public byte CODE_TYPE { get; set; }
    public byte CODE_SOURCE { get; set; }
    public byte? HELPER_CODE_TYPE { get; set; }
    public byte? HELPER_CODE_SOURCE { get; set; }
    public int QUANTITY { get; set; }
    public int REMAINING_CODES { get; set; }
    public string TRZ_ENDPOINT { get; set; }
    public int? TRZ_ENDPORT { get; set; }
}
```

But when I run the app I don't see anything on `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

I don't know how to set `TextBinding` property.

`CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION.CODE_TYPE` value is an ID. I need to show a descriptive text for each possible value. And, when I get this value I need to get its `ID` to store it on database.

Do I need an `enum` or something to get a text for each `CODE_TYPE` value?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you dont set the `ItemsSource` of the combo box. You should do something like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Path=}" DisplayMemberPath="" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

`DisplayMemberPath` defines which property of the selected item is displayed

With `SelectedItemBinding` you can bind the selected item to a property in your viewmodel.

If you only need a particular value of the selected item, use `SelectedValueBinding` and `SelectedValuePath`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION.CODE_TYPE` value is an ID. I need to show a descriptive text for each possible value. And, when I get this value I need to get its `ID` to store it on database.

Comment: as far as I understood your question, an instance of CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION is a datagrid row. You have to have additional lists for the possible values of the combobox columns. For example: what are your possible values for CODE_TYPE?

Comment: For example, "type_1", "type_2", "type_3".

Comment: CODE_TYPE in CODE_LEVEL_CONFIGURATION is a byte. You need to create some kind of mapping from the string to the byte. You could create a Type class with 2 properties: name (string) and value (byte). Then you create a List in the viewmodel containing all possible types. You bind this list to the DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource

Answer (score 0):

It's should needed to set the itemssource for ComboBox column and also bind the selected value path to view the selected value in combobox.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValuePath="{Binding CODE_TYPE}" ItemsSource="{Binding LevelConfigs}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath in ComboBoxColumn. for example, you can try by maintaing two properties (ID and Description) and create itemssource for that class. Now bind that ItemsSource to ComboBoxColumn, define SelectedValuePath as ID and DisplayMemberPath as Description like below.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValuePath="{Binding ID}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Description}"   ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}"/>
```